# How to make Pre-authentication service of ID/Refresh Token of aws Cognito using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-cognito

I want to add Pre-Authentication functionality in VueJS application for below task.

1. Validate ID/Refresh Token whether it is expired or not.
2. If IdToken is expired then i should be able to re-generate the Id Token using Refresh Token or whatever the best way.

I am getting ["expired_in" : 3600] in the Cognito response. Which I can use.

I have searched few things and found that we can use [HTTP Interceptors](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md) But it looks very confusing for me how should I use?
But how I can validate these things before each HTTP request call in my application.
It will be great if can do this on Page Load as well.

I am new in VueJS so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have found the answer!

We can use `mounted` lifecycle hook or `created` based on our need to do this task in page load (Before the Vue instance is created)